# Merge overlapping rasters but preserve all original values (R)

Tags: r, export, merge, terra, save

I have a `SpatRasterCollection`, each raster of which has the same resolution and the same set of variables. Some of the variables are numeric and some are categorical. And some cells of some rasters geographically overlap.

My goal is to combine all of the rasters into one raster while preserving all original values. `terra::mosaic()` is often used for this situation, but it does not work for my case because I do not want to aggregate the values of overlapping cells (such as in the case explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50740097/merge-rasters-of-different-extents-sum-overlapping-cell-values-in-r)).

What I instead want while combining is to somehow preserve the original values of all rasters, such as by creating new layers. For example, if a given cell has three instances of overlap across all of the rasters, and this is the most amount of overlaps that occur anywhere, then I want the final joined raster to have three versions of each variable (V1.1, V1.2, and V1.3). For the specific cell with high overlap, V1.1, V1.2, and V1.3 would all have non-NA values (each from one of the original rasters). For the cells with no overlap, V1.1 would have a non-NA value while V1.2 and V1.3 would be missing. Ideally, the output would also have some kind of ID information that indicates which rasters are involved when there is overlap.

How this can be done in R? Or is there a better way of managing this kind of data? I am asking for bigger picture ideas rather than for specific code.

Comment: I have a function in the spatialEco package `merge` that does exactly this. However, it is off of CRAN at the moment and they ticked me off enough that I am considering not putting it back up. You can however, install from GitHub or R-Universe.

Comment: Great. I could not find a function from your package called ```merge()```, but did you mean ```combine()```? I tested that one out to combine a few of my rasters, but it does not run because their extents do not match. So, would you suggest using ```terra::extend()``` before ```spatialEco:::combine()```, or should there be a different function like ```merge()``` that would account for extents differing across the rasters?

Comment: Sorry, you are correct it is `combine`.